# How can I data from url after a callback implemented to HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, callback

My html-page get callback from some social service.
After a callback implemented I need to get some data from the url.
Any idea how can I get the data from url after a callback implemented?

Comment: what is your tried code?

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like http://www.example.com/?title=first&section=second

```
function GetUrlValue(VarSearch){
     var SearchStr=window.location.search.substring(1);
}
```

`SearchStr` gives the data: `title=first&section=second`. I hope you got the idea.

Comment: But how this function is fired?